# Best way to show $\cfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

My usual approach is by definition, although this example seems slightly trickier as when we try to find $$d(f(x),f(y)) \leq c d(x,y)$$

Where $d()$ is the distance function and $c$ is a constant such that $0<c<1$

$$d(f(x),f(y)) = \cfrac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{1+y^2}$$

do not really see how we can proceed further from here

Comment: The title of your question is really weird. How $\cfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ could be a contradiction?

Comment: con(trac)tion :P

Comment: Oh, misread. xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, there is $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f'(c) = ((f(b) - f(a))/(b-a)$. Therefore, $$|f(b) - f(a)| \le |f'(c)| |b-a| \le \left(\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f'(x)| \right) |b-a|$$ However, $|f'(x)|$ has a maximum of $3\sqrt{3}/8$, attained at $x = 1/\sqrt{3}$. Thus, $f$ is a contraction with constant $3\sqrt{3}/8 \approx 0.6495 < 1$.

Comment: I had a feeling we could use MVT, but a this point in the course we had not learned it (I'm doing revision).

Answer (score 6):

If $|x|=|y|$, then $d(f(x),f(y))=0$, so we can assume WLOG that $|x|>|y|$. Then,

$$d(f(x),f(y))=\left|\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+y^2}\right|=\frac{|x^2-y^2|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$$

and

$$\frac{|x+y|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}=\frac{|x|(1+\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}<\frac12\cdot 2$$

since $\frac{t}{1+t^2}\le\frac12$ for any $t\in\Bbb R$, as can be easily checked finding the maximum of the function $g(t)=t/(1+t^2)$.

Comment: The bound is not right, less than $1$ but a lot bigger than $1/4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think that it is fixed, thank you.

Comment: You have not shown that $f$ is a contraction. It is not enough to show that $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ for all $x \ne y$; you must exhibit $k \in [0,1)$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) < kd(x,y)$ for all $x \ne y$.